# Scala REPL startup command line

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

When I start the Scala REPL, is there a way to put Scala code or source files on the command line to automatically run? I would like to have some imports done automatically (on the command line in a bash script) at startup for user convenience.

Comment: The docs mention `-i` for a start...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was googling everything I could think of, but I couldn't find squat. Then I realized that I just had to type "scala -help". Duh! The -i option works, but it requires a separate file. The -e option would be preferable because I can just enter the text into the bash script and not require a separate file. Unfortunately, the -e option does not work because it exits the REPL as soon as it executes the string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Scala REPL use [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-REPL). It is much better than the Scala REPL.

The best part about ammonite is that you can create a file called predef.sc under ~/.ammonite folder. Here you can specify SBT dependencies like `interp.load.ivy("joda-time" % "joda-time" % jodaVersion)` and also imports like `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

Now each time you start the ammonite REPL you have all SBT dependencies and imports already present. How cool is that.

Comment: Ammonite sounds great, but if you really want to see it take off, you need to get buy in from the Scala and/or Linux communities. If it is stable and available out of the box, it might have a chance to take off. Yes, bash is quirky and primitive, but I have spent lots of time learning the quirks, and I am reluctant to climb the learning curve for Ammonite unless I know that it is well supported, widely available, and here to stay. But you probably know all that already.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has a `build.sbt` file then you can add something like this to that file:

```
initialCommands in console :=
"""
import java.net._
import java.time._
import java.time.format._
import java.time.temporal._
import javax.mail._
import javax.mail.internet._
"""
```

Not sure how clear that is but it is simply a block string using triple quotes

Saves a lot of time having that collection of basic classes (whatever classes make sense for your work) handy!